# GetReferencedAssemblies throws "Operation is not supported on this platform"

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

I am working on .NET standard library and I am trying to get all referenced assemblies from entry assembly.

Here is my code

```
AssemblyName[] allAssemblies = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

This code is working perfectly in debug mode, and I am able to get all referenced assemblies from the entry assembly (UWP app).

But in release mode `GetReferencedAssemblies()`  throws `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'` exception , and I am not able to get the referenced assemblies in a uwp app.

Comment: Could you check if contains assembly that does not support release model?

Comment: Nope , it supports both mode.

Comment: Could you mind share a demo that could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: One question is what you want to do with the data? As @magicandre1981 says in the answer, UWP code is compiled into a single binary.

Answer (score 2):

Release Mode uses [.NET Native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/), which compiles managed code into native code:

> .NET Native is a precompilation technology for building and deploying
> Windows apps that is included with Visual Studio 2015 and later
> versions. It **automatically compiles the release version** of apps that
> are written in managed code (C# or Visual Basic) and that target the
> .NET Framework and Windows 10 **to native code**.

and here it is [not implemented for CoreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/5758#issuecomment-385728120).

> GetReferencedAssemblies is not implemented. We could implement it, but
> for situations like this users often have a need to actually reference
> assemblies that are otherwise unreferenced anyway (plugins, or
> platform light up), so this API is pretty deep in our backlog right
> now.